# HTTP could not register URL

Tags: windows, http, service, netsh

I'm trying start a service that uses port 8081. The service stop immediately after start. I look into event viewer and i see this:

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not
>   register URL https:// +:8081/api/. Another application has already
>   registered this URL with HTTP.SYS. --->
>   System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix
>   'https:// +:8081/api/' because it conflicts with an existing
>   registration on the machine.

I tried to register url with netsh but it says that file already exists, but i can't delete the reservation and it not appear in reservation list (netsh http show urlacl).

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http:// +:8081/api/ user=\Everyone
```

> Url reservation add failed, Error: 183 Cannot create a file when that
>   file already exists.

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=https:// +:8081/api/
```

> URL reservation delete failed, Error: 2 The system cannot find the
>   file specified.

There's anything that i can do to solve this?

Note: The service runs well on another machines.

Comment: I have same issue, and "netsh http show urlacl"  doesnot show my url "HTTP://LOCALHOST:52972/",  but I can see with "netsh http show servicestate" command,  how to delete entry from servicestate?

Comment: I found the issue, I am having a website which is also running on Port 52972, so it was not allowing my other application to run on the same port.

Answer (score 12):

There must be an existing entry covering the same url. You can verify this using the `show` command to discover what registrations exist, maybe pipe it to a file or grep it for the port number as you please, e.g.

```
netsh http show urlacl > d:\tmp\out.txt
```

Then you can delete the old entry (needs an **exact** url match - watch out for http vs https, and for trailing slashes - ideally copy paste from the output of the show command)

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=theExactRegisteredUrl
```

And add a new entry with the options you want

```
netsh http add urlacl url=theExactRegisteredUrl user=\Everyone
```

Comment: this was my issue - when copied had some spaces at the end..

Answer (score 8):

Your delete command is using a **https** address as opposed to the **http** in the add command. Remove the 's' and it should work.

Comment: Up-voting this answer b/c I also had a typo in the URL I was trying to delete--duh...

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the "+".  Try this:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://0.0.0.0:8081/api/ user=\Everyone
```